# When trying to send email using Gmail connector FileNotFoundException is occurred

Tags: wso2, gmail-api, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm using WSO2-Integration-Studio-7.0.2-linux-gtk-x86_64.

I tried the steps in https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/tutorials/using-the-gmail-connector/

When I execute the POST request in the tutorial from Micro Integrator, I got below execption.

```
[2020-07-11 00:38:22,317] ERROR {org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry} - Metadata file cannot be found at /data/wso2-products/WSO2-Integration-Studio-7.0.2-linux-gtk-x86_64/IntegrationStudio/runtime/microesb/registry/governance/connectors/Gmail/.metadata/accessToken.meta java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/wso2-products/WSO2-Integration-Studio-7.0.2-linux-gtk-x86_64/IntegrationStudio/runtime/microesb/registry/governance/connectors/Gmail/.metadata/accessToken.meta (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.getMetadata(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:1027)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.readNonXML(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:877)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.registry.MicroIntegratorRegistry.lookup(MicroIntegratorRegistry.java:206)
    at org.apache.synapse.registry.AbstractRegistry.getResource(AbstractRegistry.java:66)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.GetPropertyFunction.evaluate(GetPropertyFunction.java:326)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.GetPropertyFunction.call(GetPropertyFunction.java:115)
    at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultFunctionCallExpr.evaluate(DefaultFunctionCallExpr.java:181)
    at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultXPathExpr.asList(DefaultXPathExpr.java:102)
    at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.selectNodesForContext(BaseXPath.java:675)
    at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.selectNodes(BaseXPath.java:215)
    at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.evaluate(BaseXPath.java:175)
    at org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath.stringValueOf(SynapseXPath.java:405)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.PropertyMediator.getResultValue(PropertyMediator.java:371)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.PropertyMediator.mediate(PropertyMediator.java:110)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:169)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.TemplateMediator.mediate(TemplateMediator.java:133)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:148)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:84)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:260)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:805)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:303)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:578)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:195)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:284)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When I checked the directory of "/data/wso2-products/WSO2-Integration-Studio-7.0.2-linux-gtk-x86_64/IntegrationStudio/runtime/microesb/registry/governance/connectors/Gmail/", there is no .metadata folder. Is there any step missed in the document?

Comment: Just checked this with latest gmail connector ( version 3.0.8)  and its working fine. Could you try with the same and also provide the carbon logs and the synapse configs if you encounter the error again.

Comment: Also please give this a try in saltest pack  also https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/releases

Answer (score 0):

It worked with Micro Integrator 1.2.0.
Best way is Download Integration Studio 7.1.0 which has inbuilt 1.2.0.
Open your existing workspace with new Studio. Dont forget to copy your existing configurations from deployment.toml file.